# Deploying multiple divs based on number input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display multiple divs based on what on the user's number input. For example if user picks 3 then 3 divs are displayed.

I managed to get it working but I need to set IDs for each div dynamically for the returned values, and to set number next to the word car for example Car 1 Car 2 Car 3.

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="content"></div>
            <script>
                function myFunction(){
                var n = Number(document.getElementById("nbchambre").value);
                var content = document.getElementById('content');
                content.innerHTML="";
                for(var count = 1; count < n+1; count++){
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = 'Car : <input type="date" name="bday">';
                content.appendChild(div);
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
```

Out come should be if user puts 3
car 1:
car 2:
car 3:

Comment: `'Car ' + count + ' : <input id="' + count + '" type="date" name="bday">'`..? It's weird that you came up until rendering the div but can't figure how to append a string, did you write the code or are you working on someone else code?

Comment: You can add `div.id="Car-"+count;` after the `var div = document.createElement('div');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to concatenate `count` in to the string, assigning it to the `id` attribute and the text.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var n = Number(document.getElementById("nbchambre").value);
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  content.innerHTML = "";
  
  for (var count = 1; count < n + 1; count++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Car ' + count + ': <input type="date" name="bday" id="car' + count + '">';
    content.appendChild(div);
  }
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="nbchambre" value="5" />
```

Comment: Just a side note: you should add the car id next to car: `'Car ' + count + ': <input type="date" name="bday" id="car' + count + '">';`, as mentioned in the requirements.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the other location. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply appending the `count` in the string

```js
function myFunction() {
  var n = Number(document.getElementById("nbchambre").value);
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  content.innerHTML = "";
  for (var count = 1; count < n + 1; count++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `Car ${count}: <input type="date" name="bday">`;
    content.appendChild(div);
  }
}

document.querySelector('#nbchambre').addEventListener("input", myFunction)
```

```html
<input id="nbchambre">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```